# Dialog --input box

Tags: shell

dialog -- input box
this command is taking only one input at a time
is there any way to take multiple inputs from user at a time
for eg
ask name
    roll no
    rank 
as a input at same time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you created your own componants the answers no. One way you could solve it is to ask them to input the details with a comma between the answers. So there input would be like this "Name, 123456789, Rank" or something like that.

Comment: hi ash thanks but i want simialar to be like a input based menu 
so that i will take mulriple inputs through user at a one screen shot

Comment: #!/bin/bash
clear
dialog --menu "Select a relevent option from an arrow key" 12 60 4 1. nfs 2. samba 3. Exit 2> /tmp/menu
for n in $(cat /tmp/menu)
do
dialog --inputbox "enter name of dir,rollno" 8 40
dialog --inputbox "enter nw of dir" 8 40
dialog --inputbox "enter mode of dir" 8 40
done


see this as in this case it is asking for one input at a time , i need to get all these 3 inputs on one screen shot for dir,n/w and mode